# "Debug assertion failed" error thrown when looping iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

Error Window pops up right away, the program crashes etc.

Code:

```
void sort_star(vector<string>& product, vector<double>& star_rating) 
{
  vector<string>::iterator piter;
  vector<double>::iterator cycler;
  piter = product.begin();
  cycler = star_rating.begin();

  while (piter != product.end() && cycler != star_rating.end()) 
  {
    ++piter; ++cycler;

    cout << "/n|" << *piter << "|"; 
    cout << *cycler << " Stars";
  }
}
```

Yea so I'm pretty new and don't know too much on C++. A good explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: you increment the iterator before using it and it may be equal to end(), which is not a handle for a valid element. Increment after using iterators.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is written better than many first-timers I see,  and is pretty self-contained. Please pay more attention to code layout though. A little effort goes a long way. While you edit code and playing with it, some mess is inevitable, but why not make it look nice before you post anyway? Shows your effort, thus your respect to the forum! And we software engineers are sensitive to nitsy things. Think of this: good orators make well-calculated pauses in speech, good programmers use consistent spacing to make code more readable. and we talk in code, so that's same thing! :)

Answer (score 4):

In your while loop you increment your iterators BEFORE using them

```
...
while (piter != product.end() && cycler != star_rating.end()) {
    ++piter; ++cycler; <--- HERE
```

This means two things:

- you skip the first element
- your iterator reaches end() which is a pointer to the PAST-END-POSITION and not a valid element [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/).

**FIX** Increment at end of loop like so:

```
while (piter != product.end() && cycler != star_rating.end()) {
    cout << "/n|" << *piter << "|"; 
    cout << *cycler << " Stars";

    ++piter; ++cycler;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that worked. But would a for loop be more efficient in this case? I tried before but couldn't manage to get the same result as when I did this. Facepalmed when realizing I already assigned the iterators too, lol.

Comment: Sure can use a for loop.But there is nothing wrong with the while loop either. There is no performance gain. Compare while (https://godbolt.org/z/IqyHKe) with for (https://godbolt.org/z/7iyO8s). They yield same code.

Comment: @Gabe there is no difference. However, the suggested way will print the first elements of the vectors, too.(in case you do not wannt it, start from `vec.begin()+1`)

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing iterators after incrementing. This will

- skip the first elements to be printed
- will try to dereference the [`std::vector::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) iterator. 
  Obviously 
  `std::vector::end`:

  > Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of
  >   the container. This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to
  >   access it results in **undefined behavior**.

You could have done it in a for loop as follows:

```
for ( ; piter != product.end() && cycler != star_rating.end(); ++piter, ++cycler) 
{ // ^^                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    cout << "/n|" << *piter << "|" << *cycler << " Stars";
}
```